# main.ts results in screen going fully white

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

im trying to use vue-material

my main.ts is

```
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
    
    import App from './App.vue'
    import router from './router'
    
    import { MdButton, MdContent, MdTabs } from 'vue-material/dist/components'
    import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'
    import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'
    
    App.use(MdButton)
    App.use(MdContent)
    App.use(MdTabs)
    
    import './assets/main.css'
    
    const app = createApp(App)
    
    app.use(createPinia())
    app.use(router)
    
    app.mount('#app')
```

the specific problem is

```
    import { MdButton, MdContent, MdTabs } from 'vue-material/dist/components'
    import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'
    import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'
    
    App.use(MdButton)
    App.use(MdContent)
    App.use(MdTabs)
```

when i put this in to use vue-material, it just goes to a white screen, and idk why,

i'm new to vue but this seems weird, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what _should_ it be displaying?  you haven't shown.  but also, have you tried opening your browser's dev tools and check for any errors in the console?

Comment: it should just be displaying the standard vue starting page, the one when you create a new project with create-vue with router. I've checked dev tools and it's not helped although I am inexperienced